# Bluemix spark jazzhub addjar

Tags: git, scala, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I am trying to add a jar in a Spark Scala Notebook on Bluemix. The examples speak about using a public github url. However I have my code in a Jazzhub git repository. The problem I run into is that with Jazzhub I don't have a public url without user and password to access my jar file.

I tried several url's with userid:password etc but did not succeed to load the jar file.

Is there some example where a jar file from jazzhub is loaded into a Spark scala Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure your project is publicly available by reviewing the settings in JazzHub. Please go to the project's settings and go to Options. Next, uncheck Private if it is checked. Lastly, click save to apply the changes.

[image: The project is now publicly available]

Second, since your project is a JazzHub git repo, there will be Git Repo link provided. To find your link, go to the project's settings and go to General. Next, note the URL next to Git URL.

[image: Git URL]

Third, construct your complete download URL.

The complete URL will have the following format:

```
[GIT URL]/contents/[GIT_BRANCH]/[JAR_LOCATION]
```

For example, to download the psclnt.jar within the master branch of my sample project, the following URL would be used:

```
https://hub.jazz.net/git/hobert/libtest/contents/master/dep-jar/psclnt.jar
```

Fourth, add the following URLs to the Spark Scala Notebook:

Option 1:

`%AddJar https://hub.jazz.net/git/hobert/libtest/contents/master/dep-jar/psclnt.jar -f`

Option 2:

```
`kernel.magics.addJar("https://hub.jazz.net/git/hobert/libtest/contents/master/dep-jar/psclnt.jar -f")`
```

[image: Configure Scala Notebook to add external jars]

Comment: Does this mean that it is impossible from a non public project. In that case you would have to pass credentials, but I did not find a way to do this.

Comment: @EricCattoir I'll have to look into that further. In response to your original question. Were you able to access the jar stored in a public project on JazzHub?